# Monacaプッシュ通知APIの戻り値について

Tags: monaca

MonacaのバックエンドAPIでプッシュ通知（Push.send）を行った場合、マニュアル上はプッシュキーのリストが返ってくるとあるのですが、どういったケースで複数返ってくるのでしょうか。

現状テストしている限りは１つしか返ってこなく、またリクエストで投げた1件のプッシュキーだけが
戻ってくるで違和感はないのですが、マニュアル上は一覧が返ってくるとありますので、一覧で返ってくるケースがあるのか、もしあるなら一覧の中から今自分が送信した通知のプッシュキーがどれかどのように判断すればいいのか、ご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教授いただけないでしょうか。